# "File format does not exist or not authorized" error when altering Snowflake stage

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm creating a Snowflake file format as follows:

```
create or replace file format "db_name"."schema_name".my_csv_unload_format
  type = 'CSV'
  field_delimiter = ',';
```

I'm then trying to add this to an existing stage:

```
alter stage "db_name"."schema_name".my_unloads set
    file_format = (format_name = 'my_csv_unload_format');
```

However on running this query I get an error:

```
SQL compilation error: File format 'MY_CSV_UNLOAD_FORMAT' does not exist or not authorized.
```

I can't see what I'm doing wrong here. Do I need to add some permissions to the file format somewhere?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Worked it out, you also need to specify the database and schema in the format name:

```
alter stage "db_name"."schema_name".my_unloads set
    file_format = (format_name = '"db_name"."schema_name".my_csv_unload_format');
```

Answer (score 0):

or you can from the get-go specify the file_format when creating the stage:

```
create or replace stage "db_name"."schema_name".my_unloads 
file_format ='"db_name"."schema_name"."my_csv_unload_format"'
url = "..."
CREDENTIALS = (...)
;
```